# How I can build the layout?

Tags: magento2, layout, frontend

Currently I understand the system of templates as follows:

```
[depends layouts]    (page_layout)
↓
layout               (page_layout)
↓
magento default.xml  (page_configuration)
↓
my theme default.xml (page_configuration)
↓
module file super-module-file.xml (page_configuration)
↓ = merge.
```

I have a 2 layout: `narrow_page` and `wide_page`. I want to change block "header-wrapper" depending of the layout. But currently `default.xml` (in magento/theme) overrides this block. I can not use my `default.xml` because next time this file apply for both layouts.

How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I temporarily solved a problem by [overriding](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html) the default.xml. This is not recommended, but I feel so comfortable.

Alternative, you can use "move" for wrapping the container. For example:

**page_configuration:**

```
<container name="footer-container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="footer"/>

<move element="footer" destination="footer-container"/>
```

**default.xml:** (the destruction of the old container)

```
<referenceContainer name="footer" htmlTag="" htmlClass=""></referenceContainer>
```

*In result:*

```
<footer class="footer">
    [old footer - don't visible]
        content
    [/old footer]
<footer>
```